# Difference between two ways of adding properties to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code involves adding properties to an object based on some test cases. Here are the two ways i which I did it. I am using this object for inline styling in reactjs.

```
var myObject = {}

//some code

myObject = {
key1: value1,
key2:value
} 

//some code

myObject = {
key3: value3,
key4: value4
}
```

All the properties(styles) were not applied consistently. So I tried doing this instead and it worked properly. Please explain why this is happening.

```
var myObject = {}

//some code

myObject = {
key1: value1,
key2:value
} 

//some code

myObject.key3 = value3;
myObject.key4 = value4;
```

What is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: I would expect that the `myObject` in the first example does NOT have a `key1` or `key2` at the end of the code.

Comment: When you assign to an object variable, it gets the assigned value. Anything it was before is no longer assigned to it. This is very basic if I may say so. `a=[1,5]`, then `a=[2]`, then of course there is no more `[1,5]`. Same thing.

Comment: Every time you write `myObject = ........`, you completely redefine the object, overwriting anything it contained before. So you destroy key1 and key2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet you are not adding properties to an object, you are overwriting the whole `myObject`. In the second snippet you are assigning a single value to a key instead, ie. adding properties with values.

For example:

```
var i = {num: 1};
i.num = 2;
console.log(i.num); // 2
i = {str: "Hello"};
console.log(i.num); // undefined
console.log(i.str); // "Hello"
i.num = 1;
console.log(i.num); // 1
console.log(i.str); // "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Object.assign in first case, cause otherwise `myObject` would contain only `key3` and `key4`.

```
var myObject = {}

//some code

myObject = {
  key1: value1,
  key2:value
} 

//some code

Object.assign(myObject,{
  key3: value3,
  key4: value4
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between the two cases

the first case:

myObject = {
    key1: value1,
    key2:value
    }

means creating a new object and assigning it to variable myObject

While in the second case:

myObject.key3 = value3;

myObject.key4 = value4;

mean adding new property/value to the existing object.